# Non-existing onetoone field as zero on count?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

2 of my django models are related by foreign key as shown below

```
class User(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Car(models.Model):
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have a special situation in which I need the number of cars per user

```
Car.objects.filter(Q(user__isnull=True)|(user__isnull=False)).annotate("user").count("count")
```

The above query works perfect for all users with a car.

What i really want is this query to return count as zero for all users without a car
**Using Car as query model**

Comment: Don't think you can get that from `Car` model. The `Car` model does not know all users, it can get users that has atleast 1 car.

Comment: Ya i am almost sure about that.I was just seeing if there was a solution i missed out.